# iOS and WP Blank app not rendered in Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

iOS and WP Blank app not rendered in Xamarin Forms PCL.

I have mapped my custom control in a PCL in the below project structure.

```
Control.XForms.
Control.XForms.Android
Control.XForms.iOS
Control.XForms.WindowsPhone
```

and the create another Blank app for Xamarin (portable) by attaching the above dlls.(in the below project structure)

```
Sample.XForms
Sample.XForms.Android
Sample.XForms.iOS
Sample.XForms.Windows.Phone.
```

I have my application code in App.Xaml in `Sample.XForms` and added `Control.XForms.dll` to it.

And added `Control.XForms.Android.dll,Control.XForms.dll and customControl.dll`, similarly for the other platforms too.

Sample rendered in Android only, where in other platforms it shows empty screen.

Am i miss something.

Any  suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the assembly isn't being loaded, I'm also experiencing the same issue on iOS and Windows Phone.
I solved it by loading the assembly by loading the renderer in the start-up pages of the WP and iOS projects. For example in your AppDelegate in iOS:

```cs
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
 {
     new CustomControlRenderer(); //include assembly

     // Any other FinishedLaunching code here..
 }
```

I hope this solves your problem.